# How to implement this feature with split and join?

Tags: python

For Example I have a list of two elements `["some, string", "here"]`, in one of them is comma. When I make string by:

```
 a = ','.join(a)
```

I got `some, string,here`

and then I back to list by:

```
a = a.split(',')
```

I got `['some', ' string', 'here']`

but I want to get my initial list:

```
["some, string", "here"]
```

How can this be implemented?

Comment: It can't be implemented. There is no information about which comma should be kept in the string.

Comment: Except you want to split only on commas that are not followed by a space?

Comment: Just use a different separator. If this is not possible, use some other trick, like using a separator like ' spacespacecommaspacespace ' depending on your needs

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to read and write CSV files?

Comment: good question, I get data from external api in list format of elements and to save in database I want to make a list , and back data again in list format

Comment: Are you trying to parse and create JSON?

Comment: Parse list -> save to db string -> create list

Comment: Then use JSON to save the list as a string. Or why don't you write the list values to separate columns in the DB?

Comment: @tarp20 before `string` is there always empty space?

Comment: @PrakashDahal  its real example:['Baggins, Bilbo (Fictitious character)']

Comment: Can you show more examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easy way is to join by some other expressions instead of `,`

You can use this:

```
a = ["some, string", "here"]

a = '+$'.join(a)
#a = some, string+$here

a = a.split('+$')

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['some, string', 'here']
```

Comment: @tarp20 to be extra sure, you can use unique expressions like `+$#`

Comment: tarp20, you voted this as interesting solution and mine to be not useful. please read this: mine is exactly the same, but WITHOUT giving the code. In fact, being an IT teacher for some 30, I thought, this was a student homework question, so I didn't want to put the code, but just point out the way. One thing the above solution is still missing is the test if the masking string is contained in the source.

Comment: @zwitsch your way maybe right but your solution is clearly not understood by anyone including those who downvoted your answer. So, by next time you should be focusing whether your solution is understood by anyone or not.

Comment: @Prakash: Yeah, let's see it this way.  Thanks.